# Cannot form new instance of a function which returns itself

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

So I came across a problem where I tried to make a new instance of a function which returned itself. But I cannot do that. I am totally not getting it. Hope to get some explanation here. Below is the code:

```
function f(){ return f; }
new f() instanceof f; //returns false - should return true as per my knowledge
```

Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: "make a new instance of a function which returned itself" - You may need to clarify this. You might have meant "new instance of an object (using a constructor)"? Or, simply "try to call a function that returns a reference to itself"? There's actually not much in the way of "new instances of a function" going on in JavaScript.

Comment: This explains it pretty well: http://javascript.info/tutorial/constructor ;)

Comment: A function that returns itself does not create "instances". It just returns a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to return nothing (which will return `this` when called using `new` and `undefined` when calling as a normal function call). The class definition has been changed to capital F because objects in javascript should start with an uppercase letter to denote that they need to be called using `new`.

```
var F = function() {};

var f = new F();
```

Comment: You should completely omit the `return` from a constructor.

Comment: Thanks! you are correct on that. If the object constructor uses `return this` then `F` could be callable without new... but without actually creating an object. omitting the return forces it to require `new` and returns undefined without it.